# geocoder internet explorer issue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps, geocoding

**Hello everyone**,

i'm trying to use the google map API to display some adresses on my website. 
The problem is that doesn't work on IE...my code is like this :

```
function displayAdress (address) {

geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: results[0].geometry.location,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap-event"),myOptions); ////$("div[id^='map_canvas']").first()
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
    } else {
        alert(
        /*"Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status*/
        'Google map was unable to found the address: '+ address
        );
    }
});
```

When i use on IE, the log console throws a problem on `geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();`

Did someone ever had this problem?
Thanks for helping.

Thomas.

Comment: What problem exactly? Any error messages?

Comment: Has 'geocoder' been declared as a variable anywhere? If not, try prefixing the problematic line with the word 'var' to define it as a variable.

Comment: @BIOSTALL :  i tried to add 'var' before 'geocoder' but it's the same result

Comment: @deceze : i got 'SCRIPT445: This object doesn't manage this action'

Answer (score 0):

My guess (since you haven't included enough context) is that you have an element on your page with id="geocode" and you haven't declared "var geocode" in javascript in the global context.